# wordpress multiple meta value query is not working

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

```
$args = array(
    'p'                      => $product_id,
    'post_type'              => array( 'product' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query'             => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_ywar_product_id',
            'value'   => $product_id,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'recommend_it',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'CHAR',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo $query->found_posts;
```

The result is shown 0 only.

Answer (score 0):

You use the "p"-argument, which looks for the wordpress Post-ID. I guess you want to search the products, that have $product_id in the meta, not for the exact post with the ID $product_id. Just remove the "p" argument from your wp_query arguments.

Comment: I remove the "p" argument but still show the same result 0.

Comment: did you check that there are posts of the post type "product" having the specified meta keys/values?

Comment: Post type 'product' is in posts table and it links up by product id and meta key is in post meta table. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mk4Qyn-XVRMGPTSJrPibY1igxgGCCHtB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What i asked is, do these two criteria meet at all in your database? Your screenshot shows that the post with the id 343 has the "recommend_it" meta value, but not the "_ywar_product_id" meta_value; the post with the id 344 has the "_ywar_product_id", but no "recommend_it". The Query you posted asks for posts which have as well the meta value of $product_id in the meta_key "_ywar_product_id" AND the value "yes" in the meta_key "recommend_it". If there are no posts that have both of that, the query will return 0.